# How to declare a javascript function with properties in one line/command?

Tags: javascript, function

For now, I can do:

```
const f = () => 'result';
f.customProperty = 5;
```

Is it possible to do this in one command?
Something like:

```
const f = {
  () => 'result',
  customProperty: 5,
};
```

Ok, there is a possibility:

```
f = (() => {
  const f = () => 'result';
  f.customProperty = 5;
  return f;
})();
```

But... Isn't there something more elegant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Object.assign`, you can pass the function expression as the first argument, then pass an object with the `customProperty` property as the second argument:

```js
const f = Object.assign(() => 'result', {customProperty: 5});

console.log(f.customProperty);
console.log(f());
```